# How can I retrieve the x5t of a certificate?

Tags: jwt, certificate, x509certificate, private-key

I have private_key (.PEM), public_key (.PEM) and certificate (.CRT) and an example of a signed JWT token using this certificate. When I decode the JWT I can see that the headers contains `x5t` param. If I want to sign a new JWT token using this certificate in JavaScript, How can I retrieve that `x5t` param? Is it even possible to get this param or the client that provided me the certificate should also tell me the `x5t`?

I tried multiple packages to decode the certificate files and get the header but it didn't work.